# Where are the Mac OS X alert sound files located?

Tags: macos, audio

Is there any way I can access the files that are used for the alert sounds found in system preferences? For example, in OS X 10.6.6, there are different sounds for Funk, Glass, Hero, etc. Where are these files located?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Any files located in the following locations will available to choose as alert sounds:

```
/System/Library/Sounds/
/Library/Sounds/
/Users/< username >/Library/Sounds/
```

(Note: By default the latter 2 folders may not exist, but if created and populated with files, you'll be able to choose them in the Sounds preference pane).

Answer (score 8):

They are stored as `.aiff` files in `/System/Library/Sounds/`.

Comment: can we play from there?

Comment: Click a file, press the space bar. Quicklook does the rest :).

Comment: In Catalina this is the only location I can find any.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the path to the volume.aiff if you want to change that too

> /System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources