# Where is the OS X Volume Change Feedback Sound File located?

Tags: macos, sound-volume

I upgraded Yosemite, and turns out they changed the "pop" sound that plays when you change the volume. I have another Mac, which is on Mavericks, and I would like to get the old sound back.

I saw [Where are the Mac OS X alert sound files located?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10941/where-are-the-mac-os-x-alert-sound-files-located), and it is NOT there in Macintosh HD ▸ System ▸ Library ▸ Sounds

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The volume up/down feedback audio file is called **volume.aiff** and is located in:

```
/System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources/
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

How did you think of looking in there? This information might be useful in other cases too!

Comment: To be perfectly honest... I googled your question, word for word.

I knew it was in /System/Library, however I didn't remember the exact path.

Comment: Huh!
That's embarassing (for me)!

Comment: @gunner I was working on this answer, but Patrick was faster by one minute:) I did this in Terminal: `cd /System/Library && find . -name *.aiff`.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `System Preference > Sound`, and check "Play feedback when volume is changed".

You may have to restart your computer if it doesn't work when you check it. I did and now it works.

Comment: That wasn't my question.

Answer (score 0):

The volume up/down feedback audio file is called volume.aiff and is located in:

/System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources/
 Then you may need to restart terminal and your computer if you are editing that file.

Comment: I'm unable to find "LoginPlugins" on my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.10.4 "Yosemite".

Comment: Verified I have that folder and file (OS X 10.10.5). Odd that it is not on your system.

Comment: Any idea how to do this for Monterey 12.5.1? I'm used to changing the volume.aiff file to the "legacy" one, but I don't seem to have permissions on my new sytem.

Answer (score -2):

I use FindAnyFile from the app store to find any file anywhere on my Mac. I've had it for ages and couldn't live without it...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find the software and evaluate it themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review