# How do I change the feedback/volume sound effect back to the one in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, sound-volume

So I recently installed OSX Yosemite, and one of the immediate changes I noticed was the lack of sound when changing volume. In System Preferences I found you can turn it back on, but instead of the "pop" it plays a woodblock sounding noise. I know where to find where the sound effect is stored, but how do I change it back?

Also, it appears that the old sound effect is nowhere to be found, so if anyone knows how I can extract it from a system to use elsewhere that would be great.

Comment: Per https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151068/where-is-the-os-x-volume-change-feedback-sound-file-located?rq=1 it seems you should be able to copy the file from a computer running 10.9 (or extract it from the installer) and drop it in there