# How to restore the Mavericks version of the sound effect for the volume button for Yosemite?

Tags: audio, macos

I just upgraded my MacBook to Yosemite, and the new sound effect for the volume button is just awful. Is there a way to change out the sound file so I can hear the old version on Yosemite?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the OS X Volume Change Feedback Sound File located?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151068/where-is-the-os-x-volume-change-feedback-sound-file-located)

Comment: This allows me to find the new sound, do you have any idea where i can find the old one in order to replace it ?

Comment: See if you can find someone who hasn't updated yet; it's in the same place. Note that no-one yet has reported swapping it back actually works, but it's quite possibly a case of replacing one with the other.

Comment: @Rogue here's the `volume.aiff` file from Mavericks:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13617105/volume.aiff

Comment: The Dropbox link to obtain the old Maverick Volume sound file does not; probably expired. Here is a fresh link where to obtain the file to replace the new sound file you might not like (like me!): http://forums.macrumors.com/attachments/volume-aiff-zip.487154/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done, although you need to find the Mavericks volume feedback sound file. The filename is "volume.aiff" and (for both Mavericks and Yosemite) it is located in:
/System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources

Find the Mavericks volume feedback sound file and put it on your Desktop for easy access.

Open the Terminal and navigate to the folder containing the sound file:

```
cd /System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources
```

Create a backup of the original file in case you want to reverse the changes:

```
sudo cp volume.aiff volume.aiff.bak
```

Provide the password when prompted.

Now copy in the Mavericks sound file placed on your Desktop:

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/volume.aiff ./
```

Restart

Comment: Tried this on El Capitan (with sudo) and still got: 
`cp: volume.aiff.bak: Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly AFTER you boot into recovery (by holding <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at boot up).

From there open Terminal (under the Utilities menu) and enter `csrutil disable` (to disable System Integrity Protection).

Once you do that there are no issues though I would recommend you repeat the above process when done and enter `csrutil enable` into Terminal to enable System Integrity Protection.