# Default System Sound Location

Tags: macos, audio, preferences

I'm looking for some of the sounds that come default on OS X, like the preferences lock/unlock:

[image]

I basically just want to copy the sound files onto my desktop.

Comment: The question already has an answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/10941/60998

Comment: @alexis - that's not what i'm asking.

Comment: What's the difference? Please clarify, because it seems like exactly the same question-- and not only to me, I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

All sounds are .aiff and you'll find many by going to:

Mcintosh HD>system>library>components>

Then right click on CoreAudio.component and click 'show package contents'

Then go into Contents>Resources>SystemSounds>finder>

Note that this is different in El Capitan but is what I used in several OS's before, ie: Yosemite, Maverick, etc

Comment: Note that my answer is a different location than is stated in the previous question/answer.

Comment: i couldn't find the the lock sound anywhere in there, so it must be someplace else. if you can put the full file path (including the name of the lock sound file) in your answer that might be more helpful. thanks

Comment: that's all i know, sorry.