# On macOS 14 (Sonoma), where are the new sound files stored?

Tags: macos, audio

The answer at [Where are the Mac OS X alert sound files located?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10941/where-are-the-mac-os-x-alert-sound-files-located) points to three folders where macOS alert sounds are (or at least *were*) stored:

- /System/Library/Sounds/
- /Library/Sounds/
- /Users/*username*/Library/Sounds/

[Where are the alert tone audio files located in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210072/where-are-the-alert-tone-audio-files-located-in-os-x) suggests:

- /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AlertTones/

However, on my macOS 14 (Sonoma) laptop, the new alert sounds (Boop, Breeze, Bubble, ...) are not stored in any of these directories. Where are they?

Comment: Breeze is the same as "Blow.aiff", as far as I can tell. Boop doesn't sound new to me, at all, so may also exist as an older sound wit a different name.

Comment: I can't check Sonoma, but they're going to be in the sealed system volume, so you can't do anything with them. [You used to be able to replace them with files of the same name, but not since Big Sur.]

Comment: I don't want to change them. I only wanted to grab a copy.

Comment: As Tetsujin said, it seems being hidden. I wish to copy them too.